# Can't move my table in div (container)

Tags: html, css

I've tried to move the table, but I couldn't do that. I want to move the table that is inside div. But I only can move the table only to the left/right. I want the table to be free. What is my mistake? What I missed? Maybe I did styling wrong? Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is the code:

```css
/*Imports*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu');

body{
 background-color: #21ff00;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.division1 td{
 padding: 5px;
 border: 2px solid #000;
 color: #fff;
}

.division1{
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.division1 table{
 width: 380px;
 height: 380px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 margin: 35px 28px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #0f6bff;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Mirashraf</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

 

 <div class="division1">

  <table border="1">
  <tr>
   <td><b>Name</b></td>
   <td><b>Price</b></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>MacBook</td>
   <td>$999.99</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>iPhone</td>
   <td>$499.99</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>iPad Pro</td>
   <td>$649.99</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>Apple Watch</td>
   <td>$1199.99</td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please, help me.

**Thanks to everyone in behind.**

Comment: Do you want move the table top or bottom??

Answer (score 1):

You can set the div to absolute position and place it anywhere you like.

```css
.division1{
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly split margin to 4 parameters  as below margin: toppx rightpx bottompx leftpx , Below css will move table to center of the screen

```
.division1 table {
    width: 380px;
    height: 380px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 50px 28px 41px 40%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #0f6bff;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want the Table to be centred, you need to set margin-left:auto, margin-right:auto in your CSS for the table. This assumes your table has a width, which it does.

If you mean that you want to drag the table around, then that's a whole different question.